# Заменить символ и выделить (цветом и т.д)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Привет! Суть вопроса имеется InputField для ввода текста и textField для отображения результата. При вводе текста символы заменяются в определенном порядке. Задача некоторые замененные символы к примеру символы (А, О, Е) при замене отображались красным цветом или как либо еще главное чтобы это бросалось в глаза. Скрипт ниже:

```html
public class ConverterScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField input, txt;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Convert2();
    }

    

    void Convert2()
    {
        txt.text = input.text.
            Replace("A", "А").
            Replace("B", "Б").
            Replace("C", "Ц").
            Replace("D", "Д").
            Replace("E", "Е").
            Replace("F", "Ф");
         }   

  
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для InputField в Unity3d нет поддержки таких вещей. Зато это можно сделать для Text компонента.

Вот так:

```
void Convert2()
{
   txt.text = input.text.
   Replace("A", "<color=#ff0000ff>А</color>").
   Replace("B", "<color=#ff0000ff>Б</color>").
   Replace("C", "<color=#ff0000ff>Ц</color>").
   Replace("D", "<color=#ff0000ff>Д</color>").
   Replace("E", "<color=#ff0000ff>Е</color>").
   Replace("F", "<color=#ff0000ff>Ф</color>");   
}
```

[Вот статья](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html) от Unity3d по этому поводу.

И обязательно нужно включить галочку "Rich Text" в "Text" компоненте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Именно то что нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: @DewDew Ну так пометь галкой, раз то что нужно)